# How to construct a 95% Confidence Ellipse in R

Tags: r

See the cross-post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659749/getting-the-ellipse-function-to-match-the-dataellipse-function-in-r.

---

So I am sampling from a multivariate normal distribution in R, and am trying to figure out how to calculate its 95% confidence ellipse using the ellipse() function in the package car.

Here is some code I am running:

```
mu = c(0,0)
sigma = matrix(c(20,0,0,45),nrow=2)

z = rmvnorm(10000,mu,sqrt(sigma))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(z)
ellipse(mu,sqrt(sigma*qchisq(.05,2)),radius=1)
dataEllipse(z,levels=.95)
```

So basically I want the ellipse command to replicate the dataEllipse command.  If anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean `mvrnorm` rather than your `rmvnorm`? If you want to know the source code for `dataEllipse` in order to replicate it without loading the `car` package, just type `dataEllipse` at the `R` prompt with no parenthesis or arguments, hit enter, and then you can copy and paste the code it into your script. Lots of answers at stackoverflow appear to be relevant to your Q: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+ellipse

Comment: No I want to use rmvnorm to sample random variables from the multivariate normal (the library is mvtnorm).  And thank you for the link but I am hoping to figure out how to make the ellipse command comparable to dataEllipse....

Comment: The calculations are explained and illustrated at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21396/how-to-use-a-33-covariance-matrix-to-plot-an-error-ellipsoid/21417#21417. A user has noted that this question is cross-posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659749/getting-the-ellipse-function-to-match-the-dataellipse-function-in-r, where it has been considerably amplified and discussion has begun. Therefore this version will be closed.